# android : getting an item from a textview to another textview?

Tags: java, android, listview

i'm having two layout files. The first layout file containing some data in textview and the another layout containing one empty textview. Now, i want to pass the first layout's textview data to new layout textview when i'm using button in first layout. How can i use this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using two different activities?

Comment: no only one activity (one java file).

Comment: why this should be difficult? Upload you r code.

Comment: I can't because, it's a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, textview2 is the textview from second layout. and the

```
//to get data from text view of first layout use the following code
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);

TextView tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
// to set of first textview in second textview
textview2.setText(tv1.getText().toString
```

Comment: Okay, but it'll shows empty. What to do? And, how can i identify the tv1 textview. It's in previous layout. how can i do this?

Comment: i have shown the way in step by stp approach. please have a look on that

Comment: I've force close Error. How can i clarify that? Please give brief example

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do like this, in button click,get the view of second layout

```
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View  row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondlayout, parent, false);
```

and use below statement to get id of second textview

```
TextView text2=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.SecondTextView)
```

then get the text in the first textview using id of first one into String:

```
String s=text1.getText().toString();
```

then set this String to  2nd textview.

```
text2.setText(s);
```

Comment: It's not working. Here is my code : -
public void thdreply_Click(View view)
 {
  setContentView(R.layout.four);
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four,null);
  TextView t2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.thdview2);
  TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fthview1);
  String s = t1.getText().toString();
  t2.setText(s);
} Here, i didn't give parent. Because, i don't know about what is parent. Tell me what will i give here.

Comment: Then, how can i go to second layout?

Comment: Oh sure, but the errors are underlying in parent and text1. How can i run?

Comment: in secondline (parent) and fourth line(text1).

Comment: It's giving me force close error. I can't give more comments here. Shall we chat using any of one. If you're in GTalk then give ur id. Please.

Comment: No, there's ur name and ur accounts information only shown. Not id & number anything.

Comment: No i didn't get the solution. It shows that errors what i've told you. So only i asked you, please help me, this step is important to me